# TopSorted list execution using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, topological-sort

I have a list of tasks that need to be executed in specific order e.g Task2 -> Task1, so Task1 must be executed first and then task Task2 can run. I've built a graph of tasks and have applied the topological sorting to get the order of task execution, but now I want to execute those tasks using threads abd that's where I am stuck. Here's what I've been upto so far

```
//S = Hashset that contains tasks that has no input edges in graph
public HashSet<Task> S = new HashSet<Task> ();
for(Task n : AllTasks){ //AllTasks is an arraylist of tasks in graph
if(n.inEdges.size() == 0){
 S.add(n);}
```

}

//Empty list that will contain the sorted elements
    ArrayList outList = new ArrayList();

```
//while S is non-empty do
while(!G.S.isEmpty()){
  //remove a node n from S
    Task n = G.S.iterator().next();
  G.S.remove(n);
  //insert n into L
  outList.add(n);

  n.start(); //Starts the thread

  //for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
  for(Iterator<Edge> it = n.outEdges.iterator();it.hasNext();){
    //remove edge e from the graph
    Edge e = it.next();
    Task m = e.to;
    it.remove();//Remove edge from n
    m.inEdges.remove(e);//Remove edge from m

    //if m has no other incoming edges then insert m into S
    if(m.inEdges.isEmpty()){
    G.S.add(m);
    }//if
  }//for
```

} //while

Task class extends Thread class and each Task has a HashSet of inEdges and outEdges. How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

How many tasks are you expecting?  There are several ways to approach this.  I would choose to optimize for readability and maintainability of the code over total time to process, so I would recommend the following.

Having Task extend Thread is probably not the way to go.  If you have enough tasks, you will find yourself unable to spawn enough threads.  Your Task classes should reflect your problem domain (e.g. job dependencies).  There are already a set of classes that handle the concurrency problem domain well (the Executor framework).  By structuring your classes this way, you can easy switch from a multi-threaded implementation to a multi-process implementation.  This is how I would structure a solution.

1. Create an algorithm that takes a collection of tasks and rolls them up in to tasks that are independent of each other.  For example if you have tasks A, B, C where A depends on B but there are no other dependencies, then your algorithm should return two "rolled up" tasks.  One for "B and then A" and another for C.  Also, if A depends on C and B depends on C, then they would be rolled up into the same task (this is where the performance is not optimal).
2. Now you have a collection of rolled up tasks that can be run independently of each other.  Spin up a ThreadPoolExecutor with as many threads as you'd like.
3. For each rolled up task, create a Runnable that will run the sub-tasks in the appropriate order.  Submit each task to the executor.

Comment: well Los your solution might be a good one (in terms of performance) but I am almost done with my present solution and just need to integrate concurrency in it so just trying to look for possibilities in that area. Thanks anyway coz I got an idea of different algorithm. Cheers